# logging and debugging for qemu virtual machines

Tags: qemu

I had a `qemu` virtual-machine which crashed several times because HDD in hypervisor had no space left. This made me wonder is there a possibility to to set up a logging/debugging for `quemu` virtual-machines. I tried to start virtual-machine with `-D /tmp/qemu-debug-log` command:

```
qemu-system-i386 -D /tmp/qemu-debug-log -monitor pty -device e1000,netdev=tap0 -netdev tap,id=tap0 -m 512M -display vnc=:1 -drive file=FreeBSD10.2
```

..but this did not even create a `/tmp/qemu-debug-log` file.

In addition, `qemu` does not seem to write into `messages` or kernel ring buffer(`dmesg`). What are the best practices to enable logging for `qemu` virtual machines?

Comment: Have you tried to use libvirt's functions instead?

Comment: I would prefer to work with `qemu` directly and not through tools which use `libvirt` which in turn should use `libvirt` `qemu` driver.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`qemu` command accepts a simple `-D` switch which can create a log file. So for example including `-D ./log.txt` will create "log.txt" in your working directory.

You can access more logging/debugging options via  [QEMU Monitor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor) (e.g. `qemu -monitor stdio`).

Answer (score 8):

If you use the `-d <component>` parameter when starting up QEMU, it will enable debugging for that component.  This is useful if you have the QEMU source code and want to see detailed debugs for a given component.

For example, passing `-d cpu_reset` will enable CPU_LOG_RESET debugging which will "show CPU state before CPU resets".  See [qemu/util/log.c](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/util/log.c) for a full list of logging options.

By default, logs are written to /tmp/qemu.log, but you can specify a different log file with the `-D <logfile>` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Any logging option provided by QEMU will be far too low-level for what you need: your problem is not that the virtual hardware is misbehaving, only that the software inside the VM needs attention.

In this respect a VM is no different to a real machine, and the solution is the same. Your question suggests that the VM is running FreeBSD, so you should check out using `rsyslog` to push the logs to an external syslog server (which could be your host machine) via the network connection.

*(I'm not very familiar with the BSDs, so I'm not 100% certain that `rsyslog` is the right or only solution here, but that keyword should get you started.)*